# Returning distinct rows for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I'm working within  MySQL server and am looking to run a query for multiple userID's to return stats.

```
select 
    Firstname, 
    Lastname, 
    email, 
    count(distinct startTime) as "total Rounds", 
    MAX(starttime) as "Last Round"
from users.users 
join rounds.rounds on rounds.rounds.userId = users.users.userId
where users.userid and rounds.userId ="ENTER A USER ID HERE"
```

Any suggestions on getting a results set for multiple users?

Comment: OP, I know you've already solved this but felt it was worth it to comment this [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for aggregate functions that will likely be really helpful with problems of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the COUNT() function, but just use GROUP BY to get the count per user, like this:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, email, COUNT(distinct startTime) AS totalRounds, MAX(startTime) AS lastRound
FROM users u JOIN rounds r ON r.userId = u.userId
GROUP BY u.userId;
```

This will group all rows by the individual user, count the unique start times for that user, and the latest start time, but I'm sure you understand that concept by now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by`:

```
select Firstname, Lastname, email, count(distinct startTime) as "total Rounds",
       MAX(starttime) as "Last Round"
from users.users u join
     rounds.rounds r
     on r.userId = u.userId
group by Firstname, Lastname, email;
```

Also, learn to use table aliases.  They make queries easier to write and to read.

Comment: I suppose it would depend on OP's table, but grouping by `userId` may be enough, right?

Comment: Better to group by userid, in case there are users with the same name.

Comment: @Barmar . . . I'm grouping by the fields in the `select`.  I think that is the best approach for aggregation.